# How can reverse-SSH be established with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, reverse-tunnel

I need reverse-SSH access to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Ubuntu. Normally this isn't a problem with Linux machines but with WSL it isn't working.

First I establish the reverse SSH connection from WSL to my server:

```
ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 user@www.exampleserver.ch
```

From my server I then attempt to connect to this reverse SSH tunnel:

```
ssh user@localhost -p 19999
```

For a standard Linux machine, the connection should now be established. With WSL, instead I encounter the following type of error:

```
connection closed by ::1 port 19999
```

Why is this going wrong? How can I get this working?

Comment: Works for me (WSL on 1703). How are you starting `sshd`? What do the logs say?

Comment: It may be related to this : https://superuser.com/questions/1352714/spring-update-windows-10-ssh-client-reverse-tunelling-not-working

Comment: can you ssh yourself within WSL? in other words, is there a sshd running?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:19999:127.0.0.1:22 user@www.exampleserver.ch
```

and

```
ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 19999
```